# Adding an Appender does not work

Tags: scala, logging, logback, appender, fileappender

I am trying to get an logger and add a specific appender to it. My code is very simple but I am not sure how to get this working.

```
val loggerInstance = LoggerFactory.getLogger("FOO.class")
var fileAppender =  new FileAppender()
// fileAppender .setFile , sietPattern etc..the parameters i want
loggerInstance.addAppender(fileAppender)
```

I get an error here

```
Multiple markers at this line
- type mismatch; found : ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender[Nothing] required: 
     ch.qos.logback.core.Appender[ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent] Note: Nothing <: 
     ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent, but Java-defined trait Appender is invariant in type E. You may wish to investigate a 
     wildcard type such as `_ <: ch.qos.logback.classic.spi.ILoggingEvent`. (SLS 3.2.10)
    - Line breakpoint:loggerchange [line: 76] - addAppender
```

I have no clue what this error means and how to solve it. Can someone help me?

EDIT :

I tried to do what was told by drexin. I was not able to extend the interface and define the functions . There were only three functions , setName,getName, and doAppend. i am not sure as how to define these functions. Meanwhile i tried something and removed the errors. Please look into the code and let me know if what i am doing makes any sense .

```
val encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder()
encoder2.setContext(context)
encoder2.setPattern("%msg%")    
fileAppender.setAppend(true)
fileAppender.setContext(context)
fileAppender.setEncoder(encoder2.asInstanceOf[Encoder[Nothing]])

loggerInstance.asInstanceOf[Logger].addAppender(fileAppender
.asInstanceOf[Appender[ILoggingEvent]])
```

I know using asInstanceOf is not a smart way of coding but for now i want to make this work . When i execute this code i am getting the file in which i want to log but there is no logs inside it. I have checked for level errors , but that's not the case. i believe there is something wrong with encoder/layout. I am not sure how to fix it. Can someone show me how to either extend the class and apply the functions or what is wrong in this new code .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `FileAppender` has a type parameter `class FileAppender[E]`, but you instantiate it without providing such a parameter, so scala decides to put `Nothing` in as type. `addAppender` expects an appender of type `Appender[ILoggingEvent]`, that is what the error says. What you have to do now, is to either use an existing, or create your own subclass of `ILoggingEvent` and provide it as type param:

```
class MyLoggingEvent extends ILoggingEvent {
  // implement ALL the methods
}

val fileAppender = new FileAppender[MyLoggingEvent]()
```

Answer (score 0):

My second approach worked . I am able to see the logs now. I was making the mistake in the pattern. It just a small tweak .

```
  val encoder = new PatternLayoutEncoder()
  encoder.setContext(context)
  encoder.setPattern("%msg%n")    
  fileAppender.setAppend(true)
  fileAppender.setContext(context)
  fileAppender.setEncoder(encoder.asInstanceOf[Encoder[Nothing]])

  loggerInstance.asInstanceOf[Logger].addAppender(fileAppender
  .asInstanceOf[Appender[ILoggingEvent]])
```

I will summarize all my efforts towards logging/appending automatically and put it up soon. Hope that will help others too .